# Ember integration testing and keyboard shortcuts

Tags: ember.js, qunit

I'm having issues testing the following behavior with an integration test:

> When a checkbox is focused, and I press the space bar, the checkbox gets checked.

If I override the keyDown event in my component I can catch the event, but it doesn't seem to fall down to the normal behavior and doesn't check the checkbox.
However, when I manually test it, it works like a charm.

For the event, I'm using this:

`this.$(':checkbox:eq(0)').trigger(jQuery.Event( 'keydown', { keyCode: 32 } ))`

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: IMO, `When a checkbox is focused, and I press the space bar, the checkbox gets checked.` is the behaviour of the browser. So why do you need to test the behaviour of the browser? Just test the change event of your checkbox.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have a behavior on a component to add browsing through checkbox with the arrow keys and select the one you want via space. I wanted to test it all the way by testing the selection as well.